# Questions about responseText

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

## Overview:

I'm using the JQuery Form Plugin to send Form Data to a remote file via AJAX. The File then processes the form data and inserts it into the MySQL Database.

### Problem:

The Problem is, however, when I want to run code on a successful add, (usually completed using the "success" option, it never runs. Doing further research I found that I needed to send back "responseText" to make the function under "success" run.

### Questions:

1) Is this true?
2) How do I go about sending back responseText?
3) (If number on is that it is not true) How do I get the function under success to run?

### A few code Snippets:

JQuery (Using the JQuery Form Plugin):

```
$("#form1").ajaxForm({url: 'submit.php', type: 'post', resetForm: true, success: function () {  $('#new-paste').modal({show: false}) }});
```

I can provide the contents of the remote file (submit.php) if needed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You typically echo out something in your processing script, something like: echo json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));

Comment: @Zarazthuztra So, how would I get that back into my first page without displaying the information to the user?

Comment: When your AJAX code requests the script and the script responds the user won't see anything anyway, that's the beauty of AJAX. The result will be capture by your success function and processed.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra That's the thing, though, it isn't.

Comment: Use something like firebug to monitor the AJAX requests going out when you post from the form and then check to see what the response is.

Answer (score 0):

Change your success to:

```
function(response) {
    $('#new-paste').modal({show: false});
    alert(response); // response is the output from the php script it submitted to.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still Nothing. The Information is going into the database, but doesn't PHP return a boolean?

Comment: PHP will return whatever you want it to, usually an HTTP response code and some sort of content, usually text

Comment: @Pizzaface if you are not getting an alert dialog after submitting the form then the success function is not firing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found the solution.

The Script had to be included on the page itself, not in a remote .js file.

so:

```
<script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Should be included in the head.